# Docker EE installation: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: docker, docker-ee

I tried to follow the instruction from Docker EE instruction. 
https://docs.docker.com/ee/docker-ee/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository

I met the problem with step five: Add Docker’s official GPG key using your customer Docker Engine - Enterprise repository URL.
`curl -fsSL "${DOCKER_EE_URL}/ubuntu/gpg" | sudo apt-key add -`
When I type this command, terminal returned

```
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I tried to use the browser open the url of "${DOCKER_EE_URL}/ubuntu/gpg", it also returns 403.
Then, I thought maybe my local environment is not clean, so I rent server from DigitalOcean, but it still returned the same message.

Could someone, please point me into the right direction? Thank you!

Update: I tried to use centos, it can't work, either.

Comment: HI, @KamilCuk, I did set the variable, because of security matter, so I didn't put the variable in the question.

Comment: @KamilCuk, problem solved, thanks for your comment, it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues this morning. For me the issue is now resolved.
Looks like it takes a couple of hours before the key is available (after requesting a trial license).